# Is dual booting on a store-bought Win10 system even possible?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, multi-boot, ntfs, gpt

My situation: I got a Win10 system with ONE physical (afaik) HDD of one terabyte. I want to dual boot with Win8. I tried to do it, but it gave me an error that said the HDD was GPT and that I needed an NTFS partition if I wanted to install Win8. And that it couldn't install Win8 on a GPT disk, only on a NTFS disk. I used Windows own application **DSKMGMT.MSC** to make 40 GB NTFS partitions to install Win8 and/or Ubuntu and/or Win7 on. Apparently these aren't the right type of NTFS partitions. They are GPT-NTFS, not MBR-NTFS, which is apparently what Win8 needs(?)

Now, I've seen info that if you format a partition, it will in fact format the WHOLE physical HDD, not just the partition. (I am not used to that, I was used to the situation that one can format different partitions in different ways.)

My questions are;

1. Is that true? Because that would mean that dual booting is impossible between Win10 and Win8, which seems highly unlikely.
2. If it IS possible to reformat the HDD from a GPT partition to a NTFS partitions for Windows 8 install/dualboot on a Windows 10 system, then HOW? And yes yes, I do get that GPT is a partitioning table and NTFS is a file system, but this is the confusing error message that Win10 gives

I got a Lenovo g50-80L000H2US laptop.

Comment: Run a Clean command from command prompt and install one of the systems then. Shrink that partition to make room for a second partition. There you install your other OS.

Comment: this means installing win8 after i;ve booted into to win10? 
You're not very clear as to HOW to do what you advised

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your installer is not booting with EFI. In order to install Windows onto GPT disks, you have to boot the installer using EFI.

EFI booting (and the related "CSM" boot options) are complex enough to write a book about, but the massively abbreviated version relevant to this discussion is that a Windows installer disc (or USB disk, etc.) can be booted both as MBR and EFI. Which way you use to boot the disk will determine what partitioning scheme the installer will use and expect.

Recommendation: Figure out how to bring up a "boot device selection menu" on your machine. When you select your Windows installation media, make sure you are booting with EFI or UEFI, not with "MBR", "CSM", "Legacy", etc. If you've already created a partition to hold the Windows 8 installation, doing this should give you the option to install to that existing partition. If it won't work, then delete the partition in the installer and choose to install into the unallocated space - a new partition will be created for you.

Be aware that once you get 8 running, you may have to tweak some things to get 10 bootable again. MSCONFIG and BCDEDIT will be your tools here - Google is your friend.

Comment: if i don't boot as Legacy then i can't boot from an usb. However, I will try a UEFI formated usb now.